# When converting a PDF to a PDF using Ghos, the top title text is lost

Tags: pdf, cmd, ghostscript, pdf-conversion

When converting a PDF to a PDF using Ghos, the top title text is lost.

**Before convert:**

[image]

**After convert:**
[image]

**GhostScript Version:** 10.01.2

> gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/default -dDownsampleColorImages=true -dColorImageResolution=72 -dColorImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0 -dDownsampleGrayImages=true -dGrayImageResolution=72 -dGrayImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0 -dDownsampleMonoImages=true -dMonoImageResolution=72 -dMonoImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0 -dHaveTransparency=false -sProcessColorModel=DeviceRGB -sColorConversionStrategy=RGB -sColorConversionStrategyForImages=RGB -dTransferFunctionInfo=/Apply -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf

[Sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T1yy6ddXJwSJ7qFLDVOJmE5z4h2M6OtP/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Suggestion 1: Don't use HaveTransparency=false. That will likely damage many files. If the blue content is drawn over the black text, but using transparency so the white areas don't overwrite it, for example. Other then that, your best bet will be to open a bug report. I'm not at my desk at present (vacation) so it'll be next week before I can look at this properly.

Comment: Using the supplied command line with the example file, and current code (10.02.0 RC2) does not exhibit this problem. Checking with 10.01.2 also doe snot exhibit the problem. It could be something specific to your build, but it does not occur with the 'standard' Ghostscript build. As KJ mentions below, using -dHaveTransparency=false does lead to the text being turned into images, and significantly degraded in quality, though it does reduce the file size. I wouldn't do that myself, but obviously the choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you are getting such differences except you choice of commands is intentionally downgrading all the PDF content to inferior quality objects. (Basically the opposite to what GhostScript is designed to do.)

If I run exactly the same command on that file I seem to get a severely smaller file which can only be at severe loss of contents.

So looking at what was removed I was surprised to see coloured text converted into images, thus all the readability in that part of the file has been stripped out.

I do not get the font less text distortion your image shows, but do get the same inferior image replacing the text.

[image]

Same as before if you do not mess about with the transparency but switch to true then the text is not degraded into an image, however we can see the text is still affected to a degree and much of the other graphics severely altered by stripping their Accessibility containers thus features.

[image]

If you "Audit" the original file you will see there are no conventional images to downgrade so throwing all those downgrade image commands are superfluous to that files construction.

[image]

If we run the file through a dedicated optimisation very little can be removed primarily the 4 pages can be concentrated into 4 page streams rather than the 11 disparate ones. So little to be gained by attempting reductions.
[image]